# Is there a way in vba to create a custom legend?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, legend

I am using vba to create a pivot chart that is then filtered for the top 10 categories.  For the legend we would like to include those categories NOT in the pie chart.  I am able to create a list of the items that are not included in the pie chart, but I haven't figured out how to add them to the legend.  I tried setting the XValues alone but that didn't work.  Is it possible to create a custom legend?  I wouldn't need the color boxes but I would like to add the number and and percent similar to those that are displayed for the top 10 categories in the pie chart.

Comment: Seems to me that you are not looking for placing things in the legend but you need to add additional information next to your pivot chart? Have you considered adding an extra object where you put this info?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  I have a pivot table and say there are a list of 20 categories in it and I do the top 10 filter, so only 10 are selected.  What I would like to put in the legend is the bottom 10 since they can see the top 10 in the pie chart.  Maybe I just need to create a text box or something next to it and turn off the legend.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean: a text box or something = an object :-)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.